# Ubuntu 18.04 poor audio quality, bluetooth lag (Macbook Pro 2015)

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, mac

I recently dual booted my mac with Ubuntu 18.04. Here are a couple issues I have noticed:

- The speaker quality has dropped considerably anytime I play an audio file
- The bluetooth connection to an external speaker constantly lags or crashes

If someone could point me in the right direction in order to solve these issues, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you try restarting the Linux sound architecture by the command "pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload" and see if sound quality improves? Ciao :)

Comment: Tried this @thephoenix01 but it did not help :/

Comment: Ah, then I guess I can't be of further service. This might be an issue of Mac compatibility.